# Did Joshua break the covenant he had made with the Gibeonites in Joshua 9?

Tags: joshua

Joshua 9:15 NASB

> 15 Joshua made peace with them and made a covenant with them, to let them live; and the leaders of the congregation swore an oath to them.16 It came about at the end of three days after they had made a covenant with them, that they heard that they were neighbors and that they were living [g]within their land. 17 Then the sons of Israel set out and came to their cities on the third day. Now their cities were Gibeon and Chephirah and Beeroth and ***Kiriath-jearim***..

After having made a covenant with the men of Gibeon that they will not take their cities namely Kiriath Jearim & other cities.

Later when Joshua allots the land to the twelve tribes he allotes Kiriath Jearim to the tribe of Judah.

Joshua 15 NASB

> 20 This is the inheritance of the tribe of the sons of Judah according to their families.60 Kiriath-baal ***(that is, Kiriath-jearim)***, and Rabbah; two cities with their villages.

Did Joshua break the covenant?

Comment: Verses 15-17 are in chapter 9.  The answer is in the rest of chapter 9.

Comment: *having made a covenant with the men of Gibeon that they will not take their cities* - Where ? Please include the relevant passage.

Comment: Please change Joshua 15:15 to 9:15.

Comment: @Lucian, since the israelites were on a conquest of the land it stands to reason that the covenant of peace also iincluded the land as well,why are you always D/V my question,now im going to indulge you,im no longer going to ask any question

Comment: @collenndhlovu: Actually, the exact opposite is true, since the whole agreement was based on the assumption that the tribe in question was **not** from that land, so how could they own anything there ?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially Judah inherited slaves with the city when they took their land.

> The sons of Israel did not strike them because the leaders of the congregation had sworn to them by the LORD the God of Israel. And the whole congregation grumbled against the leaders.
>             19      But all the leaders said to the whole congregation, “We have sworn to them by the LORD, the God of Israel, and now we cannot touch them.
>             20      “This we will do to them, even let them live, so that wrath will not be upon us for the oath which we swore to them.”
>             21      The leaders said to them, “Let them live.” So they became hewers of wood and drawers of water for the whole congregation, just as the leaders had spoken to them.
>             22      Then Joshua called for them and spoke to them, saying, “Why have you deceived us, saying, ‘We are very far from you,’ when you are living within our land?
>             23      “Now therefore, you are cursed, and you shall never cease being slaves, both hewers of wood and drawers of water for the house of my God.”
>             24      So they answered Joshua and said, “Because it was certainly told your servants that the LORD your God had commanded His servant Moses to give you all the land, and to destroy all the inhabitants of the land before you; therefore we feared greatly for our lives because of you, and have done this thing.
>             25      “Now behold, we are in your hands; do as it seems good and right in your sight to do to us.”
>             26      Thus he did to them, and delivered them from the hands of the sons of Israel, and they did not kill them.
>             27      But Joshua made them that day hewers of wood and drawers of water for the congregation and for the altar of the LORD, to this day, in the place which He would choose.

New American Standard Bible: 1995 update. (1995). (Jos 9:18–27). La Habra, CA: The Lockman Foundation.